# How to avoid restart after installing prerequisite (.Net framework 4.6) using installshield 2013

Tags: installshield

I am installing .Net framework 4.6 as prerequisite using installshield.

After it is installed it restarts the system. I want to avoid the restart.

How can I achieve this ?

I used `Note it, fail to resume if the machine is rebooted, and reboot after the installation` from Behavior Tab under installshield.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the return value from the `Application to run Tab` and be sure to specify the `/norestart` parameter on the command line.

that way your installer should not be able to detect if a reboot is required.

Comment: /q /norestart /log %temp%\netfx451_prq.html

Comment: mmm that should work do you have any other prerequisit that could cause the reboot? or the install log? (could be optain launching the installation with /lvoicewarmup "<path to log file>"

Comment: I'm not having another prerequisite in my installation. Probably it's happening because of installing .NET update on another update. But not confirm it.

Comment: does it reboot during the installation without any warning?
just after the installation of the .net or during the installation of the .net?